# How to load scripts from templates in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have index.html with all the source Javascripts and ui-view defined in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <title>Projects</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/external/c3.min.css">
    <link href="resources/css/external/colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="resources/css/external/googlechart.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/dndTree.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <!-- Controllers for dashboard -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/shared/headercontroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/views/homepage/project/projectcontroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/views/homepage/conceptmodel/cmdboardcontroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/views/homepage/repository/repositorycontroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/views/homepage/ontology/ontdboardcontroller.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/views/overview/section/component/componentmanager.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/views/overview/section/component/componenttemplate.js"></script>

    <!-- document viewer js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/views/analysis/docviewer/manager/docviewermanager.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/views/analysis/docviewer/model/solrdocument.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/views/analysis/docviewer/controller/docviewercontroller.js"></script>
</head>

<body id="db" class="homepage" ng-app="ipaApp">
    <ui-view></ui-view>

</body>

</html>
```

I have around 150 such js files and currently all files are loaded when the webapp loads, resulting in increased loading time. I want to minify all these files and load files related to dashboard in index.html and others in the children templates for better user experience. I tried to move those script in templates but didn't work out. Is it possible to do so? What could be the best way to solve this?

Comment: Look into `grunt`, `gulp` or `webpack` which are build system often used to do such tasks and are well documented.

Answer (score 0):

A common approach is to move script tags to the end of the body tag, so this way, the content (html) is loaded and the scripts are loaded the last, so the user experience is better.

Despite the first time it could take some time to completely load all the resources, after that, you'll see the results, since you won't have to load any other resource again the user experience is so much better than if you load some scripts every time in a different template. That would be distribute the initial time in many portions (for every template). Not to mention that you might switch from one template to another more than once (and this way you load again the same resources). This is kind of a matter of perspective and what your final goal is: invest some time at the beginning and not after that, or just divide that time in minor portions, for every template you load.

With the first approach it would be something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
    <title>Projects</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/external/c3.min.css">
    <link href="resources/css/external/colorpicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="resources/css/external/googlechart.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body id="db" class="homepage" ng-app="ipaApp">
    <ui-view></ui-view>


<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/dndTree.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <!-- Controllers for dashboard -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/shared/headercontroller.js"></script>
    <!-- ... -->

    <!-- document viewer js -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/views/analysis/docviewer/manager/docviewermanager.js"></script>
    <!-- ... -->


</body>

</html>
```

Hope this help :)